# How to grep all text after a certain point

Tags: linux, grep

I have the following output from the uptime command:

```
14:48:51 up 23:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

Although I would like all text after "14:48:51 up 23:34,  2 users,  load average:" e.g.:

```
0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative you may be better of with `sed` e.g.

```
uptime | sed -e 's/.*average: //g'
```

or

```
uptime | sed -e 's/.*average: \(.*\)$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just look in /proc/loadavg to get the same information.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' /proc/loadavg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<your grep command> | cut -d':' -f5
```

This will give the output you require